# Discover if .NET family update is installed

Tags: .net

Microsoft has released a family update for .Net. It can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=B9DE7937-2C12-4F16-AD66-A31B83931953&displaylang=en). Is there a way to find out if this update is installed on a PC using the .NET framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link which describes what other components get installed as part of the update. It may be that you never had some of the original components installed so if you have them it may be an indicator.

http://www.pagestart.com/netframeworkfamilyupdate.html

Answer (score 0):

You can reflect on one of the updated assemblies that come as part of that update. Several ways to go about it, all involve reflection. Here's a quick bit of code you could try:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.Load("System.Web"); // not sure if that's actually a valid long name 
AssemblyName asmName = asm.GetName();

if ( asmName.Version > "3.5.0000" ) return true;
```

You can also get your CLR runtime version with: Enviroment.Version;

I hope one of those helps you out. There's plenty of docs on the MSDN about reflection:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx